# How can I test an event triggered by a date in the future in specs2

Tags: scala, testing, playframework, specs2

I would like to test the behavior of a function that has different behaviors depending on which it is being executed, is there a way to define/simulate the date in `specs2`?

Example how would I test the following?

```
def dateDependingFunction:Boolean = currentDate > aSetDate
```

I would like to be able to write something like

```
"My Date depending functions" should{
// here somehow set a date fulfilling `currentDate > aSetDate`
 "return true" in {
    dateDependingFunction:Boolean must beBeEqualTo(true)
 }

 // here somehow set a date fulfilling `currentDate < aSetDate`
 "return false" in {
    dateDependingFunction:Boolean must beBeEqualTo(false)
 }
}
```

Comment: You shiuld use service that retutn current time and mock it in your tests.

Comment: any code snippet?

Comment: In your `dateDependingFunction` somewhere you can see something like `System.timesCurrentMill()` you should replace it with `timeService.getCurrentTime()`. In your test you can use mock library like `Mockito` and initialize `timeService` with mock. I'm never did this with your test framevork so I'm unable to give you an answer. Only hint on how it can be achived.

Comment: @talex in my function I have something like `new org.joda.time.DateTime()` but I get your idea, thanks fr your input

Comment: There is no way to do that in specs2 but I would also advise to create a "TimeService" in your components to be able to set the date as you wish. I think this is also better than using a static method like `setCurrentMillisFixed` because then you introduce dependencies between your tests.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using joda you can try [DateTimeUtils.html#setCurrentMillisFixed](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTimeUtils.html#setCurrentMillisFixed(long))